# Agrupar filas que disponen de un campo en común

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, bootstrap

me acabo de encontrar con un problema. Lo que quiero hacer es agrupar las filas cuando el movimiento es el mismo. Este es el estado actual de la tabla.

[image: Imagen1]

Los datos los obtengo a través de ajax en formato JSON. Para realizar la tabla utilizo Bootstrap. He buscado en su documentación y no he encontrado nada.

[image: Imagen2]

¿Alguna idea? (si necesitáis más información, sin problemas).
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero como piensas agruparlo si aunque sean del mismo tipo, el nombre es diferente?

Comment: El nombre va en relación con el número del movimiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un nuevo Array para almacenar sus valores y agruparlos antes de mostrarlos en la tabla. Saludos

```js
var arrayJSON = [{
     TMP_DS_TIPO:"prueba 1",
     GRUPO:"saludos 1",
     TOTAL: 100,
 },
 {
     TMP_DS_TIPO:"prueba 1",
     GRUPO:"saludos 12",
     TOTAL: 50,
 },
 {
     TMP_DS_TIPO:"prueba 2",
     GRUPO:"saludos 2",
     TOTAL: 20,
 }];

 var movimientos_encontrados = new Array();
 var nuevo_ArrayObject = new Array();

 arrayJSON.map(function(valor, indice){
  if(movimientos_encontrados.indexOf(valor.TMP_DS_TIPO) === -1){
   
   movimientos_encontrados.push(valor.TMP_DS_TIPO);
   nuevo_ArrayObject.push(valor);
  }
  else{
   
   var recuperado = movimientos_encontrados.indexOf(valor.TMP_DS_TIPO);
   var objetoRecuperado = nuevo_ArrayObject[recuperado];
   objetoRecuperado.TOTAL = objetoRecuperado.TOTAL + valor.TOTAL;

  }
 });
 var table = '<table>';
 nuevo_ArrayObject.map(function(valor, indice){
  table += '<tr> <td>'+valor.TMP_DS_TIPO+'<td><td>'+valor.TOTAL+'<td> <tr>';
 });
 table += '</table>';
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="demo"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me ha servido, muchas gracias. :D